# Update multiple record in DB Table Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, database, bulk

I want to do bulk insert and update to my custom model collection, right now I can only do insert multiple records to DB like this:

```
public function __construct( 
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
) { 
    $this->connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $this->resource = $resource; 
}

public function execute(){
  $data[]['name'] = 'Bond'
  $data[]['code'] = '007';
  $data[]['name'] = 'Lancelot';
  $data[]['code'] = '002';
  $this->connection->insertMultiple($this->resource->getTableName('agent'), $data);
}
```

this will add those 2 data records to my database table `agent`, the problem is when I execute this multiple time it will insert new data, I want to update the data if the `code` column is same

Comment: code is your primary column into the table, right?

Comment: yes looks like 'code' is primary key of table.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya  `code` is not primary key, this table doesn't have primary key

Comment: Then you need to set that one, and due to that reason you face the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `insertMultiple` with `insertOnDuplicate`. Try this:

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
 * @param ResourceConnection $resource
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
) {
    $this->connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $this->resource = $resource;
}

public function execute()
{
    $data[]['name'] = 'Bond';
    $data[]['code'] = '007';
    $data[]['name'] = 'Lancelot';
    $data[]['code'] = '002';
    $this->connection->insertOnDuplicate($this->resource->getTableName('agent'), $data);
}
```